# Would like help with HTML page layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I will appreciate your help dividing my **LTR** html page.

I would like the page to fit 100% height & width in the browser.

I am not sure whether to use table / Divs.

Please advise.

---

### [image: desired layout]

Comment: You should probably begin by looking at the myriad of questions already asked on this topic: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=site:stackoverflow.com+100%25+page+divs+vs+tables&pbx=1&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+100%25+page+divs+vs+tables&aq=f&aqi=&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=9079l9231l1l2l2l0l0l0l0l81l134l2l2&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=bd71108a3b251f45&biw=1920&bih=1019

Comment: What have you tried? post the HTML you have tried and maybe someone can show you where you are going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `div`s and:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
#container {
    height: 100%
}
```

Then, you can simply add `div`s inside `<div id="container"></div>` and set `width: ??%` and `height: ??%` and it will work as expected.

Here's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/k5n5W/

Answer (score 1):

You should not use tables for this.  According to the W3C, tables are for displaying tabular data only and should never be used for structuring your page layouts.

Take the time to read about liquid layouts using CSS and you'll save yourself a lot of headaches later.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the 960 grid system @ www.960.gs  They have a custom layout generator that is absolutely amazing.  It uses divs, is really flexible and will help to make sure your content lines up EXACTLY how you want it to.

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

```
html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
body { height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: This doesn't in any way answer the question.

Comment: The only thing the OP was specific about was making whatever was on the page fits 100% of the browser window space, which my answer achieves. All that is needed is to make sure the content fills 100% either way. I recently solved this problem myself by doing the above. Next time, read the question and test the answer before rubbishing it.

Comment: I can read thanks.  What he asked was advise on whether he should use tables or divs.

Comment: @Steve Taylor: I haven't downvoted you, but your answer is not complete. `body { height: 100% }` won't do anything without also having `html { height: 100% }`.

Comment: A little explanation would probably help your answer immensely.